# Power BI Google big query connector

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

I am trying to use the Power BI Google Big Query (beta) connector to connect to my BigQuery dataset from PowerBI.
For the connector configuration what authentication mechanism should be set up? I have the Oauth Client ID and Secret key for web application, also have the service account.

thanks